# Make body borders invisible/different color

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

Java LibGdx Box2d

I would like to make body borders invisible or at least different color. One body should work as sensor and thus not be visible on the screen. I could not find a valid answer for that in hours and I cannot believe there is no such option in this library so I assume I must have missed one liner somewhere in Docs.

I would like to make this square transparent/invisible or at least different color but still keep it to discover movement of these circles.

[image]

Looking over stackoverflow and googling it in docs.

Closest things I found:
[Make invisible body line box2d libgdx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47381020/make-invisible-body-line-box2d-libgdx)

so maybe the only solution to this is setting some flags in render method or unique render methods for each body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I can see on your screenshot is Box2d's shapes **for debugging**.

They were not designed to have adjustable visuals and are here only to show you the precise shapes and positions of your Box2d's entities.

According to the wiki (https://libgdx.com/wiki/extensions/physics/box2d#debug-renderer):

> Debug Renderer
>
> The next thing we are going to do is setup our debug renderer. You generally will not use this in a released version of
> your game, but for testing purposes we will set it up now like so: ...

You will need some other kind of renderer if you want to adjust the visuals. For example:

- ShapeRenderer, for simple shapes (https://libgdx.com/wiki/graphics/opengl-utils/rendering-shapes)
- SpriteBatch, for textured visuals of any kind (https://libgdx.com/wiki/graphics/2d/spritebatch-textureregions-and-sprites)
- PolygonSpriteBatch / CpuSpriteBatch / any custom renderer you may find or create yourself

Retrieve the positions / shapes / sizes of your Box2d entities and use one of the more advanced renderers to draw shapes or textures in positions of your Box2d entities. Box2d is not designed for drawing stuff, it just simmulates the physics and gives you position / rotation of bodies and some other info about its world.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the box the same color as the background. [Adding color to lines Box2d (EdgeShape)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18447017/adding-color-to-lines-box2d-edgeshape)
This post shows how to change the color

Comment: Good idea but it still doesn't answer my question which is more technical. I do not know HOW to do that ;)

Comment: I am having a hard time giving code solutions without seeing any code. You might want to add the code you are working on to the post :)

Comment: @54vvy I also found this post which seems to be asking a pretty similar questions to what you are asking. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/63642/coloring-box2d-body-in-libgdx